# Javascript interval looping

Tags: javascript, loops

How can a loop proceed like this :

I have my variables like this :

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var maximunNumbers = 6
var eachRound = 2
```

I want to print the numbers like :

```
In round 1 : print array[0] and array[1]
In round 2 : print array[2] and array[3]
In round 3 : print array[4] and array[5]
In round 4 : print array[0] and array[1] //numbers repeat themselves from here
In round 5 : print array[2] and array[3]
and so on ...
```

Comment: What I have so far makes no sense and that's why I am posting a question here. @nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var maximunNumbers = 6;
var eachRound = 2;


var i, k;
for( i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
    var result = 'In round ' + i + ' : ';
    for( k = 0; k < eachRound; ++k ) {
        var array_index = ( ( i * eachRound ) + k ) % maximunNumbers;
        result += '  array[' + array_index + '] = ' + array[array_index];
    }
    console.log( result );
}
```

> In round 0 :   array[0] = 1  array[1] = 2
>
> In round 1 :   array[2] = 3  array[3] = 4
>
> In round 2 :   array[4] = 5  array[5] = 6
>
> In round 3 :   array[0] = 1  array[1] = 2
>
> In round 4 :   array[2] = 3  array[3] = 4
>
> In round 5 :   array[4] = 5  array[5] = 6
>
> In round 6 :   array[0] = 1  array[1] = 2
>
> In round 7 :   array[2] = 3  array[3] = 4
>
> In round 8 :   array[4] = 5  array[5] = 6
>
> In round 9 :   array[0] = 1  array[1] = 2

https://jsfiddle.net/shctc5eu/

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write an internal counter that steps by 2.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var maximunNumbers = 6;
var eachRound = 2;
var intCount = 0;
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
  print array[intCount] and array[intCount+1]
  intCount=intCount+2
}
```

This will print your array[0] and array[1] the first time.  The second time, intCount will be 2.  So it will print array[2] and array[3].

Just be careful of how high "i" counts to.  Written like this, intCount will go out of bounds on you.

Comment: but I just want to reach array[5] and return to array[0]

Comment: So, have "i" stop counting at 5 instead of 10.  When you run the loop a second time, make sure you re-init "intCount" along with declaring "i" in the for loop.